# How to insert data into sql without using insert into command

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Recently, I created a database with 10 tables. Each table contains 10 columns. I want to insert 10 rows for each table, but I don't want to use the `INSERT INTO` command because it takes to much time and effort.

I am using Oracle11g.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use insert. It would be the straight-forward way to insert data into tables. Besides, "i want to insert 10 row for each table": which which values? Is this for testing? Do you want to create random values? Or do you have a data source where you have the data stored already?

Comment: i have the data in word document i want to insert into database its too long process to use insert into command i want to know any alternatives

Comment: @joshua Do you know any programing languages?  Your best bet is to copy-paste the data from the Word document into a text file and then use perl, python, java, etc. to generate your insert statements.  However, if you don't have much experience with programming, you best bet may be to do it manually.

Comment: kk any gui method to insert the data i dont want to do in command line

Comment: Not that I know of, but if you find one, please let us know.

Comment: you say too much time and effort but it would have been less effort to do it yourself than to make a stack overflow account and a question

Comment: You could also take a look at using SQL*Loader, but the learning curve there is unlikely something anyone would consider "low effort."

Comment: @joshua if you want more performance, you may leave classical `insert into table values( ...` template, and use `bulk insert`

Comment: Obviously, you can use a graphical user interface like sqldeveloper. It is available for free. It can also be used for importing data from a .csv file.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what the data is. Here are two ways:
1. Instead of inserting individual values with

```
Insert into Table (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)
```

you can insert the results of another query with

```
Insert into Table (col1, col2) SELECT Top 10 col1, col2 from Table2
```

Method 2. If you have some data in Excel, you can write a string function next to each line to construct an insert value  statement and copy it down and paste the resulting code into your DB IDE. eg. in cell C1 put

```
="INSERT INTO TABLE (col1, col2) VALUES ('"&A1&"','"&B1&"');"
```

Comment: any alternatvies to insert into command by just copy paste the data in database im using oracle 11g

Comment: @joshua: I wonder if you understand what Alan is telling you. You can copy the values from your Word tables to Excel and then create a column with a formula to simply *generate* your insert statements, so you don't have to write them one by one. Doesn't this help you?

Comment: Actually, that's a great idea!  +1 for one of the more creative ways to generate SQL that I've seen in awhile.

Comment: Although @Alan, just being a little picky here, but it might be a bit more intuitive if the data were transposed in your solution so the columns would be A1, B1, C1, etc.  Might as well have Excel rows/columns correspond to database rows/columns.

Comment: Fair cop. Wasn't thinking. I do this all the time so should have been thinking more! I've changed the answer to reflect the columnar perspective.

Comment: Method 2 is what I used to do, but I have found that using Excel for this is not the best use of my time. What I prefer doing is exporting  the data into a CSV file, and then picking it up in `notepad++` where I can do Regular Expression search and replace. Much faster... although it can require some creative regex work.

Comment: That's dangerous because you are playing with the data. I like the Excel approach because it encapsulates the data and ensures that any changes are made separately. Of course, if you use a string manipulating function in code and pass the data in, that would be fine too.

Comment: finally found sql devloper its helps me a lot thanks for everyone

Comment: Please accept the answer if it satisfies you need